# Optimal binary tree search

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I want to write a function that gets a root of a sorted binart tree and a value.

The function returns whether the value is in the tree or not.

A node in the binary tree looks like:

```
struct Node {
    int key; // Contains the key in the current node
    Node* right; // Right subtree. All nodes in it will be GREATER than the current. May be NULL
    Node* left;  // Left subtree. All nodes in it will be SMALLER than the current. May be NULL
};
```

I've come with the following solution:

```
bool searchBinaryTree(int value, Node* root) {
    Node* currNode = root;
    while(currNode) {
        if((currNode->key) < value) {
            currNode = currNode->right;
        } else if((currNode->key) > value) {
            currNode = currNode->left;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Does anyone know of a more optimal solution?

Thanks!

Comment: the above could possibly obtained with the use of _recursion_: i.e the `while` loop could be replaced by a function call , but I don't know if the complexity will be lower.

Comment: This probably is pretty much optimal

Comment: Per node there are three possibilities: the value you are looking for can be in the left subnode, the right subnode, or you have found the droids you are looking for. That's what this function does. To further optimize: the only external variable is the construction of your binary tree. If you balance it perfectly (or as close as possible), your overall performance will improve.

Answer (score 3):

> The need of optimization comes when the code is heavily used and after applying metrics and analysing their results. Typically the only optimizations that are worthwhile are those that gain you an order of magnitude performance improvement in terms of speed.

### All optimization is premature unless:

1. A program is too slow.
2. You have a measurement showing that the optimization could improve things.

So the answer in your case is: **your code looks optimal enough for your needs and no optimization is required.**

Comment: Well... he could ignore performance and go talk to some computer scientists or math person living in the clouds. They would then suggest to use recursion, which in the real world would lead to a complete slaughter of all that is performance, while at the same time make it very hard if not impossible for the compiler to optimize the code, depending on if/how recursion unrolling is handled. There are many pre-mature things out there, not just manual optimizations.